# How to allow only English letters or empty string in RegEx of WPF 2010 C#?

Tags: regex

I would like to check only English letters or empty string in C#. I tried to write regex, however it does not work:

@"[^$|a-zA-Z]"

Any advice will be helpful:)

Comment: The string "does not work" is not a built-in error message in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^[a-zA-Z]*$"` will match 0 or more lowercase or uppercase letters. Note this does not match numbers or whitespace.